# Intersection of two genomic ranges to keep metadata

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am trying to find intersection of two genomic ranges (gr1 and gr2) and keep metadata from one of them

```
gr1
chrI [1, 100] * | 0.1
chrI [101, 200] * | 0.2

gr2
chrI [50, 150] + |
```

`intersect(gr1, gr2)` will remove metadata, where
`subsetByOverlaps(gr1, gr2)` return:

```
chrI [1, 100] * | 0.1
chrI [101, 200] * | 0.2
```

where metadata is saved, but intersection is bigger than real (the same as in initial gr1 start/end)

How can I get an intersection range and keep metadata?
to get the range:

```
chrI [50, 100] * | 0.1
chrI [101, 150] * | 0.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming you don't have cases of multiple ovelaps

```r
> library(GenomicRanges)
> gr1 = GRanges(c("chrI", "chrI"), IRanges(start=c(1, 101), width=c(100, 100)), mcols=data.frame(foo=c(0.1, 0.2)))
> gr2 = GRanges(c("chrI"), IRanges(start=c(50), width=c(101)))
> o = findOverlaps(gr1, gr2)
> grl1 = split(gr1[queryHits(o)], 1:length(o)) # You can't mendoapply on a GRanges object
> grl2 = split(gr2[subjectHits(o)], 1:length(o))
> foo = function(x, y) {
+     rv = x
+     start(rv) = max(start(x), start(y))
+     end(rv) = min(end(x), end(y))
+     return(rv)
+ }
> unlist(mendoapply(foo, grl1, y=grl2))
```

The output is:

```
GRanges object with 2 ranges and 1 metadata column:
    seqnames     ranges strand | mcols.foo
       <Rle>  <IRanges>  <Rle> | <numeric>
  1     chrI [ 50, 100]      * |       0.1
  2     chrI [101, 150]      * |       0.2
  -------
  seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

It'd be more memory efficient to iterate over `o`, but this gives you the idea.

In cases of multiple overlaps, one could use `intersect()`, then `findOverlaps()` with that and then continue on with the procedure demonstrated above (or iterate over the overlaps).